# Malevolent and Cruel Sentient Earth

Tags: story-identification, sentience

I read a story somewhere online in the last couple of years. It was point of view from our planet from the start of life to near future.

The narration indicated that the world did not care for life and hated being disturbed from its slumber. Repeated attempts to destroy life at attempted. Eventually the planet starts to enjoy watch the violence and suffering of life. Eventually the planet in intrigued when an ape kills another with a stick. The planet sends cruelty (ice age) after cruelty (famine etc)  at the ape and each time the ape things survive.

Eventually the planet feels pride at the apes. "They have been tempered in war and suffering and they shall be unleashed upon an unsuspecting universe" - paraphrasing.

Anyone recognize it and link me to the story. Its not very long, maybe a thousand words if not less.

Comment: Did it mention any specific events? How close are the words in that paraphrasing you mention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I FOUND IT. At long last. It feel so good to have finally found the collection of posts.

Here it is:

https://1d4chan.org/images/4/49/Terra_Is_Alive.png

Best of luck with all your own story identifications. Closure is awesome.